Tricentis Tosca - XScan extension works incorrectly
I tried using XScan in Tosca, but something went wrong. It identified the element incorrectly.
For example, when I tried identifying the 'User Name' field, XScan identified the position of this element incorrectly as displayed in the UI.
Could this indicate a bug in the XScan extension of Tosca?
Note: I have already set the scale of my screen to 100%.


